# Interpretation of results - logit model with interaction term

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, interpretation

I have run a pooled logit regression (using R) with a dependent variable of probability of CEO turnover. I have several binary and continuous independent variables, and an interaction term between binary and continuous variable.

I am confused about interpreting the results, since interaction term does not have a marginal effect, and it is said that interpreting the logit model coefficients do not make much sense.

What do you recommend to interpret the results, especially the interaction term?

Thanks in advance

I have read several sources, but it seems tricky and complex to follow

Comment: Further, helping with how to interpret results would benefit a lot from seeing some results and the expression used to generate the model.